# $X\geq0$ and $X$ a random variable, show that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}n\cdot E(\frac1X\cdot 1_{X>\frac1n})$=0

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

The only result I got so far is, that the limit has to be smaller than 1. This I derived via monotonicity and $\frac1X$<n. I have no clue how to continue and a hint would be appreciated.

Comment: $X \leq 0$ and $X > \tfrac1n$?

Comment: Presumably  $X \ge 0$ is meant.

Comment: @WimC I have edited that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You noted that $\frac{1}{nX} 1_{X>\frac{1}{n}} \le 1$ almost surely. Since $E[1] < \infty$, this satisfies the condition in the dominated convergence theorem, so you may push the limit into the expectation.

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} E[\frac{1}{nX} 1_{X>\frac{1}{n}} \le 1]
= E[\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{nX} 1_{X>\frac{1}{n}} \le 1 ] = E[0] = 0.$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem.